# Ability to Use Formatting Hotkeys for Comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown

In the questions/answers you can markup text easily using hotkeys like Ctrl+B for bolding text, Ctrl+K for code, etc. Why isn't this done for comments since comments use 'mini-Markdown' (just not via hotkey)? It would surely save time commenting.

Comment: Laziness to the max when asking someone what they have tried. +1.